# How to remove array index from json object while convert array to jsonobject php?

Tags: php, json

I want to remove array index while converting array to json using `json_encode()`. Below is my code;

```
  $arr = array('id' => $_POST['id'], 'name' => $_POST['name'], 'model' => $_POST['model'], 'color' => $_POST['color']);

  $result = array('success' => 1, 'message' => "Updated Successfully", json_decode(json_encode($arr)));

  echo $result;
```

Below is response in which I want to remove "0";

```
{
"success": 1,
"message": "Updated Successfully",
"0": {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "vvs",
    "model": "vvs",
    "color": "vvs1"
   }
}
```

I want below result;

```
{
"success": 1,
"message": "Updated Successfully",
"data" : {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "vvs",
    "model": "vvs",
    "color": "vvs1"
     }
}
```

Comment: That's not a valid JSON object. All elements of an object have to be in `key: value` format.

Comment: I already defined key value in array function. I am new in PHP. please give me suggestion @Barmar

Comment: PHP allows you to mix named and numbered elements in an array. JSON doesn't.

Comment: Can you write answer for me how can I take request POST parameters in jsonobject in api response? @Barmar

Comment: `echo $result` would throw a `Warning: Array to string conversion`

Comment: Are you sure you want `$arr` nested like that? How about `{
"success": 1,
"message": "Updated Successfully", "id": "3", "name": "vvs", "model": "vvs", "color": "vvs1"}`

Comment: Start with the actual, valid JSON that you want and work backwards from there. Check your chosen structure at https://jsonlint.com/ before continuing though

Comment: I can't write an answer if I don't know what your API is supposed to return.

Comment: plz see my edited question @Barmar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I need to change your code to this to even get the result you're talking about:

```
$arr = array('id' => $_POST['id'], 'name' => $_POST['name'], 'model' => $_POST['model'], 'color' => $_POST['color']);

$result = json_encode(array('success' => 1, 'message' => "Updated Successfully", $arr));

echo $result;
```

The problem you are facing with the key "0" is that you cannot have a value in JSON without a key (as other have stated in the comments). Notice that you set the key `success` and `message`, but you don't set a key for `$arr`.

I think you should add a key `data` or something similar to it like this:

```
$arr = array('id' => $_POST['id'], 'name' => $_POST['name'], 'model' => $_POST['model'], 'color' => $_POST['color']);

$result = json_encode(array('success' => 1, 'message' => "Updated Successfully", 'data' => $arr));

echo $result;
```